# How to replace multiple words in a sentence from array of texts?

Tags: javascript

I have a sentence and an array of texts.

```
sentence = 'Hi I am fine. how are you'
arrayOfTexts = ['Hi','I am','how','how are','how are you']
replacedText = '** * ** fine. *** *** ***'
```

So what I want to do here, I want to compare the sentence words that are matched with an array of text values and replace them with stars ' * '.

**Conditions:**

1. The first preference to replace the words is higher when multiple words are matching rather than single.  Exp:`how are you` to replace with `how are you` not `how` nor `how are`. You can think as higher grams replace first.
2. Currently, I only want up to 4 grams (4 pairs).

**My solution**
I am converting my sentence up to 4 grams and search every pair one by one but I think its a little bit redundant.

```
sentenceArray = ['Hi I am fine', 'I am fine .', 'am fine . how', 'fine . how are', '. how are you','Hi I am', 'I am fine', 'am fine .', 'fine . how', '. how are', 'how are you','Hi I', 'I am', 'am fine', 'fine .', '. how', 'how are', 'are you','Hi', 'I', 'am', 'fine', '.', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

**My Question**
Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Seems like a case for regular expressions. I'm having trouble determining what you're trying to replace the text with though?

Comment: Sort array of texts based on length of words and start replacing them starting from index 0..

Comment: @Nick text with stars. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the `arrayOfTexts` by string length (put the longest first), then turn it into a regular expression that alternates between each possible string, and perform a global replacement:

```js
const sentence = 'Hi I am fine. how are you';
const arrayOfTexts = ['Hi','I am','how','how are','how are you']
  .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
const pattern = new RegExp(arrayOfTexts.join('|'), 'g');

console.log(sentence.replace(pattern, 'FOO'));
```

For more dynamic replacement, you can pass a callback to `.replace` instead, or use `$&` in the replacement string to be substituted with the matched substring there.

If the `arrayOfTexts` may contain characters with a special meaning in a regular expression, [pass them through an escaper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) before passing to `new RegExp`.

Comment: @aravind The sorting is only needed to ensure the order of phrases that start with the same character, eg `how` vs `how are`. If the phrases do not start with the same words, then it doesn't matter in which relative order they're in in the pattern, so sorting by length works.

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can replace the words with stars exactly the same format?

Comment: Like I said in the answer, *For more dynamic replacement, you can pass a callback to .replace instead* - the replacer function takes as an argument the matched substring, so you can take its length and repeat `*` that many times with `String.prototype.repeat`